# Compiler Design - Can we convert a generic nested loop into a single loop?

Tags: for-loop, compiler-construction

This is my compiler design assignment question. If nested loops can be converted into single loop, Why bother using nested loops?

"3.Converted a nested ‘for’ into a single ‘for’ construct." -compiler assignment.

Comment: Have you tried to answer the question? If so, please edit your question body to include more details about what you tried and what you are struggling with. [See our homework policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @JoeSewell I could not understand how can a nested looping construct be made into a single loop. Isn't that question specific.? The question is just single line and no more details are provided. For example while printing a matrix i can use a single loop with row*column iteration and calculate row index as i%(number of rows) and columns as i%(number of columns) but I dont think there is a way generalise this question. If nested loops could be made into a single loop then why should we bother using nested loops?

Comment: So your question is why a programming language would allow nested `for` loops?

Comment: @SrinathSureshkumar: if the matrix is contiguous and the indices are only used to select an element (for example, for copying), then you can convert the nested loops into a single loop which just advances a pointer. There are other such transformations for other specific cases. I don't know what answer that question expects, though.

Comment: Search for "Strength Reduction". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction. For short inner loops, also "loop unrolling"  could be employed.